# Volume defined in docker-compose.yml shows up empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - db_import:/import
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3338:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  db_import: {}
  dist: {}
```

The problem is that even though I have a `dump.sql` file in my `db_import` folder (inside the same folder where `docker-compose.yml` resides), I find that `docker-compose exec db ls -al /import` shows an empty directory. I've tried restarting all docker containers without any improvement.

**Why is this directory not passing my content through?**

Comment: I'm thinking the relative path is not inferred automatically, and should instead be something like ./db_import. Otherwise it assumes absolute pathing. That, or a docker_volume already exists with the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing:

```
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - db_import:/import
(...)
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  db_import: {}
  dist: {}
```

You created so called **Named Volumes** with names `db_data`, `db_import` and `dist`. Docker doesn't tell us where those volumes are stored (and we shouldn't care about that). That kind of volumes is used to share data between containers and they do not have access to anything from your host machine.

If you want to share files beetween your host and container you must use **Mount Binds** instead - syntax is almost identical, you just need to replace `db_data` and `db_import` with absolute paths to that directories:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - /PATH/TO/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /PATH/TO/db_import:/import
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3338:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
#volumes: That part isn't needed unless you use "dist" volume somewhere
#  db_data: {}
#  db_import: {}
#  dist: {}
```